# Basic If-statement not working properly - Python

Tags: python, if-statement

This code is for a basic adventure game I am writing. I keep getting dead('you become a workaholic etc...') even when I input 'refuse' or 'sdef' in Python.

Help!!

```
from sys import exit

def dead(why):
   print why
   exit(0)

def nyc():
   print '''You arrive in NYC and have a bank job lined up. will you take it or leave it?'''

   choice = raw_input('> ')

   if 'take' or 'accept' in choice:
       dead('You become a workaholic and die of heart failure.')

   elif 'refuse' or 'decline' or 'leave' or 'not' in choice:
       bum()

   else:
       dead('Its banking or no deal buddy...you dead')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'take' in choice or 'accept' in choice:
```

Correct one is this. Otherwise your `if` statement evulates always `True`. You have to write every condition in there.

- Wrong

  if something or something1 and something2 in somewhere:
- Correct

  if something in somewhere or something1 in somewhere and something2 in somewhere: